# Directory issues!

Tags: php, html

I have a directory problem.

If i have a file in the following place.

public_html/v3/index.php

And within that I want to reach the following

public_html/navigation/sideLogIn.php

I have used the following:

```
include("/navigation/sideLogIn.php");
```

For some reason, that code isn't finding what I expect.
What am I doing wrong?
I assumed / went to root?

Thanks

EDIT.

The following also doesnt seem to want to work, any ideas.

```
        echo '<img src="$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/images/users/tiny.jpg" alt="" />';
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to understand what is relative path, absolute path, and what it to do with DOCUMENT_ROOT

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as your root.  This way, whether you are developing on your home computer or the script is running on the server, the document root will change automatically.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/navigation/sideLogin.php');
```

Also, it is a good idea to use single quotes in this situation as php tries to parse the script for variables if you use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/navigation/sideLogIn.php');
```

this is the same as /fromroot/public_html/navigation/sideLogIn.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want an absolute directory, instead of a relative one, use

```
~/public_html/navigation/sideLogIn.php
```

~ will give you your home directory, through it looks weird and isn't usually used from a webpage perspective.